# Navigating from a page (in a shell) to another page (another shell) and passing Token value in MAUI

Tags: c#, .net-maui

[image]enter image description here[image]
[image]
[image]
Error while navigating from a login page that's in the appshell to the homepage in another shell.

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("PageShell")
```

Comment: Why would you have 2 Shell in your app?

Comment: I need to add have a flyout when user login is successful. But user login is already in a shell(Appshell). Although I can remove the user login from the shell, but navigating to another shell while passing the token is the problem

Comment: I still don't understand why you have 2 Shell, in my humble opinion you should only have 1 Shell in your app.

Comment: All I need is to redirect to a flyout or shell that has a flyout after a successful login

Comment: If it is possible to disable the flyout on the login page. That should be enough for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first:

> disable the flyout on the login page

You can set the Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled" in the login page xaml, such as:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyMauiApp.LoginPage"
         Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">
```

**Another way**

In addition, you can try to remove the LoginPage from the AppShell and set the Login Page as the MainPage in the App.cs:

```
 public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new LoginPage();
}
```

And then navigate to the Shell you want in the login button event, such as:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var parameter = xxx;
    App.Current.MainPage = new MyShell(xxx);
}
//Change the MyShell's construction method

public MyShell(ParameterType parameter)
{}
```

Finally, a project usually just have a shell, so you can just use AppShell.

Comment: I want to redirect to a new page inside a shell i.e enter the shell and pick the homepage

Comment: If I navigate directly to a page, it doesn't display the tab until I click the item on the flyout

Comment: So you can try the first way I said, just put all the pages in the AppShell, and disable the LoginPage's flyout. Then you can use `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("PageYouWant")` to navigate to the page. @OlayemiRondo

Comment: Or you can try to use the second way and use `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("PageYouWant")` behind the `App.Current.MainPage = new MyShell(xxx);` in the login button's clicked event. @OlayemiRondo

Comment: I have fixed the issue around disabling flyout for the login. But the second one is Navigating to a new page and pass parameter  through AppShell. At the moment, I can navigate to a new page(HomePage) with parameter but it's not going through AppShell because the Tab is not showing on first load, the tabs only show when i click the flyout item

Comment: So the problem has been resolved? @OlayemiRondo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247817/discussion-between-olayemirondo-and-liyun-zhang-msft).